# How do I initiate an object of a class, that has a private value of a sub class

Tags: java

So for example I have this code.

```
public class BST{
private Node root;
private double[] start;

public class Node{
    private double[] coords;
    private String address;
    private Node left, right;
    private double distance;


public Node (double[] coords, String address){
    this.coords = coords; this.address = address;
    this.distance = distance(coords);
    }
//calculates 
public double distance(double[] destination){
    double tempLat = start[1] - destination[1];
    double tempLong = start[0] - destination[0];
    tempLat = tempLat*111;
    tempLong = tempLong*85;
    double Distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tempLong, 2)+Math.pow(tempLat,2));
    return Distance;
}

}

public BST(Node root, double[] start){
    this.root = root;
    this.start = start;
}
```

It is a Tree, with a subclass Node.

My problem is, in the Main class, I am having trouble properly initializing the BST object.

I do this:

```
BST mcdonaldsLocations;
Node rootM = new Node(rootCoords, rootAddress); 
mcdonaldsLocations = new BST(rootM, start);
```

And it doesn't work. So I did some tinkering and got this

```
BST mcdonaldsLocations = null;
Node rootM = mcdonaldsLocations.new Node(rootMCoords, rootMAddress); 
mcdonaldsLocations = new BST(rootM, start);
```

which compiles, but has a null pointer error.

Comment: In this case, you can't. Because you need a BST before you can create a BST.Node, and you need a BST.Node before you can create a BST. But have you considered making BST.Node static?

Comment: Follow the examples available to you in the JDK, like java.util.Map and its Map.Entry.

Comment: Can you elaborate. I am still somewhat of a novice, Do you mean making BST.node a static class? How does this help?

Comment: As immibis described, right now you have a chicken-and-egg scenario. If you make BST.Node static, you can create it independently, without the need for an instance of BST. Though alfasin makes a valid point too. Another option is skip the nested class approach.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I see now. Also I kindhave to make a nested class because the constructor of Node uses the method distance(double[]), which relies on a private value of BST. Am I correct in saying this?

Answer (score 2):

I would not implement `Node` as inner class but from demo purpose:
you can use a static factory - remove the constructor from your code, and do:

```
public static BST generateBST(double[] start, String rootAddress) {
    BST bst = new BST();
    bst.start = start;
    Node root = bst.new Node(start, rootAddress);
    bst.root = root;
    return bst;
}
```

Comment: Will I need to define a constructor that takes no arguments BST() for this?

Comment: You may, but it's not mandatory, if you don't do so an empty constructor will be used as a default constructor. Why don't you try both options ? ;)

Comment: Ok, I see, I was unaware that they are default like that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @dragon66 when you're using a static factory - the constructor shouldn't be used outside of the factory, it should become private and get called only from within the static factory (same as with some of the implementations of Singleton!). So the initialization of BST becomes part of the work of the static factory. Pay attention to the first sentence of the answer: "...remove the constructor from your code..."

Comment: @dragon66 you're right, I changed the order of the actions.

Comment: @dragon66 :))) you caught me with my pants down... :D

Comment: By the way, as a side note, if you're writing a code that is so vulnerable to the order of actions - you're probably doing something wrong (not you Dragon!). The main problem here is that the constructor calls another public method - that's a bad practice! one of the problems that can come out of this is in case of inheritance when the overriding class changes the implementation of distance.

Comment: Exactly, the design and coupling between the inner and the outer classes are not completely right. At least a code smell.

Comment: Exactly! that's why I treat this example only as a demo of how things can be achieved - but in practice I would not create Node as an inner class.

Comment: Should I create a distance method within the Node class, that still access' the privat start variable in BST class.

Nevermind, this is already what I am doing. Im kind stumped on how to get around this dependencies.

Comment: @Martin I have no idea what "start", "destination" and "distance" are standing for. Each one of them should be in the class that it belongs to. A general rule of thumb is that a variable should be declared in the narrowest scope possible!